# Textbox can't be referenced by id value in js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple login form with HTML and CSS, but I'm unable to use `document.getElementById()` for my textbox.

The following error occurs in the console of my browser:

> TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

P.S: I'm a noob at js

My code:

```
<div id='logon'>
<input type=text placeholder='Username' id='un' style='width:50%; height:10%;'><br>

<input type=password placeholder='Password' id='pw' style='margin-top:2%; width:50%; height:10%'><br><br>
<button id='button' onclick='auth()'>Enter</button><br>
</div>
<script>
function auth(){
var x = document.getElementById("un");
var y = document.getElementbyId("pw");
if(x.value.toString()==="bla" && y.value.toString()==="bla")
    document.getElementbyId("invalidd").innerHTML = "<div id='invalid'>Invalid</div>";
else
    alert("Welcome!");

}
</script>
```

Comment: capital B in getElementById

Comment: your `b` needs to be uppercase `getElementById`

Comment: document.getElementById - It is a type. Must be capital B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `b` is in upperCase format, like :

```
document.getElementById
___________________^
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test_1')); //Valid function
console.log(document.getElementbyId('test_2')); //Invalid function
```

```html
<span id="test_1">Test 1</span>
<br>
<span id="test_2">Test 2</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: Glad I could help brother... welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer is what you're looking for, mark it as the **[Correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/299570)**.